# Calculating $\frac ab \bmod c$ from $a \bmod c$ and $b \bmod c$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am very weak at number theory. 
I wanted to calculate $$\frac ab \bmod c$$ , where $b|a$ and $c$ is a prime number. This should be an integer answer. But $\frac{(a \bmod c )}{(b \bmod c)}$ could result in a non integer answer. How can I solve it to get an integer.

Comment: Other than forgetting about the fraction, and noting that $a/b$ is an integer (provided $b \ne 0$), I don't see any other *general* method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\gcd(b,c)=1$ use the (extended) Euklidean algorithm to find integers $u,v$ such that $ub+vc=1$. Then $b^{-1}\equiv u\pmod c$ and $ab^{-1}\equiv au\pmod c$.